# Комплексная оценка PC

Tags: железо, производительность

Суть проблемы: Есть два ПК которые полностью идентичны в плане железа и софта. (возможны незначительные различия по софту) При этом один из двух ПК (оба выполняют роль терминалов) заметно притормаживает по сравнению со вторым при выполнении одних и тех же программ (графика, несложные расчёты)
Поверхностная диагностика (на предмет выявления программ отжирающих процессорное время) результатов не принесла. Перечень запущенных служб и программ в автозагрузке идентичный.

Вопрос: Какая программа сможет провести комплексную оценку быстродействия (графика, проц, оперативка, жёсткий и т.п.) и выдаст удобочитаемые результаты? 
Цель: Сравнить результаты оценки на 2-х терминалах и выявить первопричину "тормозов"

Comment: Лучшее средство анализа причин — хороший программист. Вы уверены, что проблема конкретно в процессорном времени, а не в скорости винта, например? Или в производительности сети?

Comment: Ммм... проблема наблюдается при запуске любого софта. Речь не о том, что конкретно моя программа тормозит.

Comment: И да, я не уверен что проблема именно в процессорном времени. Именно поэтому я и написал "графика, проц, оперативка, жёсткий и т.п." и ни слова про процессорное время.

Comment: Окей, то есть вы _можете_ воспроизвести тормоза на вашем коде? Это уже хорошо. А на простой программе, без доступа к диску, тормозит?

Comment: Эмм... нет, я не могу воспроизвести тормоза в моём коде. Ибо тормозит абсолютно всё. Мой код тут чуть более чем совсем ни при чём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIDA64 программа для оценки и тестирования пк